# Positioning an element related to the position of another element

Tags: html, css

I have four divs:

```
<div class="a">I'm A</div>

<div class="b">I'm B</div>

<div class="c">I'm C</div>

<div class="x">I'm X</div>
```

All div elements including X are fixed positioned.! I want to reposition div X related to the position of div B such that div X is on top of div B. How can I do this stating the fact that all elements should have a fixed position, that is, they wont move when the page is scrolled? And if div B is repositioned, div X will also reposition to stay at top of div B.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to accomplish this is if you nest `.x` inside of `.b`:

```
<div class="a">I'm A</div>

<div class="b">I'm B
    <div class="x">I'm X</div>
</div>

<div class="c">I'm C</div>
```

Then absolutely position `.x` within the context of `.b`.

---

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jTzZU/